# Complete Rails app backup including external gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backup

Let's say right now I zip/tar a copy of my current Rails app directory, put it in a flashdrive and store it 10 years.

How can I be sure that rubygems.org will be around when I try to run this application in 10 years time?

For this reason, I wanted to know if there's a way to store a complete rails app, including all gems defined in the `Gemfile`, the databases and all files in a backup, so I'm sure I will be able to execute it in the future.

Comment: dismiss the actual claim that a flashdrive might last 10 years (it's just an example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `bundle package` command to package all your gems in vendor/cache.

More info: http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html

As for your database I'd just dump the data into a file (e.g. an SQL dump). Your migrations should cover the structure.

Comment: So simple, yet so powerful. So Rails. I love this framework more and more everyday. Thank you very much